# JsRender and accessing nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jsrender

I am using jQuery and JsRender to render my template.

Here is my jsfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kWBFS/8/

Could anyone please tell me how should I access values of particular arrays?

Currently I'm gettin only `[object Object]` and don't know how to access its contents.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't link source code from github. Check the error console: Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/master/jsviews.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: I updated your fiddle so that the source links correctly now

Comment: Thanks cfs, it seemed to work for me. Sorry, first time using this. Any ideas about the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used jsRender before, but this template seems to give you the correct output. You need to iterate over the items in the R1 array using a `for` loop:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for R1}}
        Column: {^{:#index+1}}
        {{for #data}}
            <p>{{:K1}} {{:K2}}</p>
        {{/for}}
        <br>
    {{/for}}
    <br>
</script>
```

Comment: You're right! Somehow usage of `{{for #data}}` didn't came into my mind previously. Thanks a lot!